# sort my python list based on multiple values

Tags: python, list, sorting

I want to sort lists as the following:

input:

```
mylist = [['12','25'],['4','7'],['12','14']]
```

output:

```
[['4','7'],['12','14'],['12','25']]
```

the current code that I use only sorts the first number of the lists:

```
def defe(e):
   return int(e[0])
mylist = [['12','25'],['4','7'],['12','14']]
mylist.sort(key=defe)
print(mylist)
```

output:

```
[['4','7'],['12','25'],['12','14']]
```

Comment: you just want `mylist.sort()`, sequences are *already sorted lexicographically*. However, your sorting strings, not ints. So you *probably* just want to convert everything to ints, `mylist = [[int(x) for x in sub] for sub in mylist]` then just use `mylist.sort()`

Comment: Note, "variable" is the wrong terminology here.

Comment: The built-in python ```sort()``` will use the first list entry as the primary sort key, the second as the secondary sort key, and so on.  It already does what you want -- remove the "key" parameter:  ```mylist.sort()``` will give you what you want

Comment: `sorted([['12','25'],['4','7'],['12','14']], key=lambda sl:(list(map(int,sl))))`

Comment: Note: you can also simply sort initially on the 2nd number, then sort that result on the first number (because sort is stable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: (int(x[0]), int(x[1])))
```

Output:

```
[['4', '7'], ['12', '14'], ['12', '25']]
```

If sublists are longer than 2, then

```
sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: list(map(int, x)))
```

is better.